# Node.js Multer Ajax - page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload file in Node using Multer and Ajax technology.

Node Server side code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser =    require("body-parser");

var multer  =   require('multer');

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, '../shop/photos');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname + '.jpg');
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');                

app.post('/postphoto', upload, function (req, res, next) {

 res.end("asd");
});
```

Express ejs:

```
      <form id="uploadForm"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          action="/postphoto"
          method="post"
          >
      <input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
      <input type='text' id='random' name='random'><br>
      <span id = "status"></span>
      </form>
</div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
        $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            error: function(xhr) {
          status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            },
            success: function(response) {
            $("#status").empty().text(response);
            }
    });
    return false;
    });
```

File is saved and this part works correctly. The problem is that post route is opening a new page with comment "asd". Looks like /postphoto is not returning to Ajax. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by live server. If you are using live server in Vs code it injects a code into your HTML file so that it can reload after every change.So when you are uploading a file into your local folder, your web page gets automatically reloaded.

To solve this:-

1. Close your live server
2. Go to .vscode/settings.json
3. Add this  `"liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles":["**"]`
4. Restart live server

This will stop automatic reload .(Don't forget to use reload after making a change in your code).